# Randomize images every 2 seconds Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to randomize three images every 2 seconds in my webpage.

Currently here is my code

```
function randomImage() {
  var fileNames = [
    "image1.png",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.png"
  ];
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileNames.length);
  document.getElementById('#background').innerHTML = 'url(' +
    fileNames[randomIndex] + ')';
}
randomImage();
setInterval(randomImage, 1000);
```

I think there is a syntax error as nothing is showing up. I've vetted through it a few times but it's taking a very long time as I'm very new to Javascript.
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `style.backgroundImage` property of the target element, not `innerHtml`. Also when using `getElementById` DOM query you shouldn’t include the # only the id’s name.

```
function randomImage() {
  var fileNames = [
      "image1.png",
      "image2.jpg",
      "image3.png"
    ],
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileNames.length),
    backgroundImage = 'url(' + fileNames[randomIndex] + ')';

  document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
}

randomImage();
setInterval(randomImage, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
document.getElementById('background').style.background
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work(**NOTE:** untested code):

```
var randomImage = function() {

 var fileNames = [
    "image1.png",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.png",
];

var randomIndex = Math.Round(Math.random() * fileNames.length);

//Change myImage to the id of your image. (example: <img id = "myImage" src = "meme.png"></img>)
document.getElementById("myImage").src = filesNames[randomIndex];
};

randomImage();
setInterval(randomImage, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` parses a string into HTML if you want to change the url of an image's location there are two situations that are common in which that would be applicable:

#### Using an `<img>` tag

> ```
>      <img src="image1.png">
>      document.querySelector('img').src = `image${i}.png`;
> ```

#### Using JS Property `imageBackground` of the Style Attribute

> ```
>      <figure class='bkg'></figure>
>      document.querySelector('.bkg').style.imageBackground = `url(image${i}.png)`;
> ```

---

It might seem like there's a lag but the index is random thus:

> 2sec image1, 2sec image1, 2sec image1, etc... *that's already 6sec of the same index*

Random index of a length of 3 the chances of an index being picked consecutively is 33% of the time. Note the console logging the index every 2sec.

---

This demo switches the actual tag (replace `<b>` with an `<img>` or `<div>`) using the `display` property of the `[style]` attribute.

### Demo

```js
function randomImage() {
  var images = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('b'));
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  console.log(randomIndex);
  for (let img of images) {
    img.style.display = '';
  }
  images[randomIndex].style.display = 'block';
}

setInterval(randomImage, 2000);
```

```css
b {
  display: none;
  font-size: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:70%;
  min-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<figure class='bkg'>
  <b></b><b></b><b></b>
</figure>
```

Comment: this is really cool!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```js
var ele = document.getElementById ('background') ;

var fileNames = [
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeY54SaYkaOxxyXlu_ng21EMIBZvJjnZBNQAOsIh_0_6Tvu9et"
] ;

function randomImage() {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileNames.length);
  ele.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + fileNames[randomIndex] + ')' ;
}

randomImage() ;
setInterval(randomImage, 1000) ;
```

```css
#background { width: 200px; height:150px; }
```

```html
<p id="background"></p>
```